# screen doesnt start in autostart

Tags: scripts, screen, cron, reboot

Note: If i start the script manually as root user it works fine.

I added my script to crontab. Its called via @reboot :

```
@reboot sh start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This script get called after booting and it looks like this:

```
touch file1.txt

screen -X -S miner kill >> miner.log
screen -dmS miner -L
screen -S miner -p 0 -X stuff "bash startminer.bash^M"
```

the file.txt gets generated and the output message of the kill command ("No scrren session found") gets logged in miner.log. But after that the screenlog.0 file contains just an "#" and the screen doesn't exists. But just at the autostart, if I start it manually it works fine. The start.sh has 777 permissions. Why does the screen not starting or dieing?

Answer (score 0):

In file `start.sh` you can have mistake is:
The first file you must add command is: `#!/bin/bash`. I think after you change it works